# Passing parameter to a function in init-file

Tags: init-file

I'm trying to create a `.emacs` file that works on multiple platforms. Therefore, I declare a variable with a path for each platform

```el
(defvar macosx-p (string-match "darwin" (symbol-name system-type)))
(defvar gnulinux-p (string-match "linux" (symbol-name system-type)))
(defvar mswindows-p (string-match "windows" (symbol-name system-type)))

(defconst macosx-ps "/Users/xxx/")
(defconst gnulinux-ps "/home/xxx")
(defconst mswindows-ps "D:/xxx")
```

How can I pass one of the `-ps` variables to a function like this?

```el
(if macosx-p
   (progn
    (setq org-capture-templates
     '(("t" "TODO" entry (file+headline (concat macosx-ps "file.org") "Inbox")
          "* TODO %?")))))

(if gnulinux-p
  (progn
   (setq org-agenda-files (quote
   ((concat gnulinux-ps "file.org")
    (concat gnulinux-ps "others/"))))))
```

I want `macosx-ps` to output my path string.

Comment: Why use `string-match` and `symbol-name`? You could simply test `(eq 'darwin system-type)`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of defining multiple versions and picking up the right one each time, it would make more sense to define a single variable according to the system that Emacs is running on.

```
(defconst somepath (cl-case system-type
                     ((gnu/linux gnu gnu/kfreebsd) "/home/xxx")
                     ((darwin) "/Users/xxx")
                     ((windows-nt cygwin) "D:/xxx")
                     (t (expand-file-name "~"))))
```

Note that if you want to refer to your home directory, you should call [`expand-file-name`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Name-Expansion.html#index-expand_002dfile_002dname) rather than hard-code values.

If `somepath` refers to a directory, call `expand-file-name` to build a path to a file in that directory. To evaluate part of an expression which is otherwise given in literal syntax, use a [backquote](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html#Backquote) rather than a quote, and a comma to indicate subexpressions to evaluate.

```
(setq org-capture-templates
     `(("t" "TODO" entry (file+headline ,(expand-file-name "file.org" somepath) "Inbox")
          "* TODO %?")))))
```

Answer (score 0):

As xuchunyang pointed out, I need to add a backquote (´) and , to my list, like this:

```
(if gnulinux-p
  (progn
   `(setq org-agenda-files (quote
   (,(expand-file-name "file.org" gnulinux-ps)
    ,(expand-file-name "others/" gnulinux-ps))))))
```

Now everything works.

Comment: Isn't your backquote in the wrong place? It's quoting the `setq` so the whole expression won't do anything. Unless this is within a macro?

Comment: Where would you place it?

Comment: `(setq org-agenda-files \`(,(expand-file-name "file.org" gnulinux-ps) ,(expand-file-name "others/" gnulinux-ps)))`

Comment: Or just `(setq org-agenda-files (list (expand-file-name "file.org" gnulinux-ps) (expand-file-name "others/" gnulinux-ps))`